# How do I use SessionID for subsequent requests after successfully logging in

Tags: community, soap-api, .net, session

One of our provider has a salesforce system in place and they have send us the URL. I added the reference as a **Web Reference** since adding it as a **Service Reference** had some issues.

Now, I am able to successfully login to the service and get the session ID. Now question is that how can I use the session ID in my subsequent Upsert request?

- DoI have to add it to the SOAP header? If so, how?

Comment: Can you share the custom WSDL that has been provided to you? It would appear to be a non-standard API implementation. Have the built their own API implementation for integrating with Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

As mention above you are able to get session id,so you have to just set the soap session header for session id and make your callout you don't have to set anything else for auth just your request.

Answer (score -1):

This cookbook recipe on [developer.force.com](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/setting-up-your-salesforce-com-web-services-api-applications) has a code example showing how to log into Salesforce, obtain the sessionId and set the value in the SessionHeader class of .net

Another walkthrough of Salesforce integration with .net can be found in this technical library article [Integrating Force.com with Microsoft .NET](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET).

Comment: That's what the problem is. I have added the reference and seems like I do not have the same version because my login() method takes SFCredential rather than <username,password> Am I dealing with a a diffrent version of it than what this documentation is dealing with?